# Does transitioning a bathroom fan duct diameter work even if the fan's outlet is the smaller dimension?

Tags: bathroom, ducts, exhaust-fan, exhaust-vent

According to numerous charts online, I would need an 80 CFM bathroom fan to exhaust via a 6" round rigid duct in order for my planned long length run to work properly.  If the exhaust outlet of a fan is 4", would using an adapter to 6" work, or is the fan's outlet size the bottleneck of the system?

Comment: It's not just the diameter, it's the length.  As mentioned below, the 4" neck does provide some restriction, but running a 6" duct after a 4" transition will produce total less head loss than a 4" duct of the same length.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Duct diameter to length is a matter of duct friction, where larger ducts have less friction. A very short section of 4" contributes some friction, but not very much.

Reduced to the absurd, if a 4" diameter fan that can manage 80 CFM is connected to an infinite diameter duct (also known as "the outside wall") it works.